# How to check if a NSProgressIndicator is currently animated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsprogressindicator

`NSProgressIndicator` has methods called `startAnimation:` and `stopAnimation:`, but no method that I can find to check the state (whether it is currently animating or not). How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just keep a `BOOL` value somewhere in your class that you set to `YES` or `NO` when you start and stop the animation respectively.

Comment: I can. But I'd rather not subclass all the Cocoa classes I use :)

Comment: Why would you have to subclass all of them? Can't you just keep a BOOL property in your delegate class or something? Or do you have more than one progress indicator?

Comment: I have more than one, yes. Also, each object should keep information about its own state, not external classes.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be storing the state of a control in the control itself.

The progress indicator control doesn't provide access to its animated state because unlike something like a text field, the user can't change the state of the control. You will never be in a situation where the state of the control changes without your code initiating it. Because you are the one who sets the state of it, so you should keep track of it.

Cocoa uses the Model-View-Controller pattern and a progress indicator is a view. If you store state in the control then you are violating the MVC pattern.

Your View should reflect your Model at all times, and the Controller is there to ensure the view and model are kept in sync.

You should either use Cocoa Bindings to bind the animated state of your progress indicator to a `BOOL` stored in your model (preferred) or implement code in your controller class to control the animated state of the progress indicator when there is a change to a `BOOL` stored in your model.

Comment: There does not appear to be a `isAnimating` property for for `NSProgressIndicator` (at least I can't find it in the docs), thus there is no way to use Cocoa Bindings for this :(

Comment: It's the `animate` property.